# Relation between runge domain and polynomial convexity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Are these concepts the same? Just to state the definitions

> **Definition 1** A domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a *Runge* domain if every function $f \in H(\Omega)$ can be approximated, uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, by polynomials in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Here $H$ stands for the space of holomorphic functions. While the definition of polynomial convexity is stated as

> **Definiton 2**  Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of holomorphic polynomials on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let 
>   $\|P\|_K = \sup\limits_{z\in K}|P(z)|$ be the sup-norm of $P \in \mathcal{P}$ on $K$. The set
>   $$
>     \hat{K}
>     = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : |P(z)| \leq \|P\|_K \ , \ P \in \mathcal{P} \}
> $$
>   is called the polynomially convex hull of $K$. If the compact subsets $K \subset \omega$ have compact polynomial hulls $\hat{K}$, then we have a polynomial convex domain.

I have a book that gives an example [Wermer] which shows a domain $\Omega\in\mathbb{C}^2$ which is biholomorphic to a bidisc, but which is not a runge domain.

However another paper says the following:

> "On the other hand , biholomorphic images of polydiscs can fail to be polynomically convex, see [Wermer]"

Just for completeness sake, here is the theorem both papers refers to

> **Theorem 1** [*Wermer*]> There is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which analytically
>   (holomorphic) equivalent to the bidisk, but which is not a runge
>   domain

So one paper refers says that the domain is not Runge, while the other says that it fails to be polynomically convex.

**Hence my question is as follows: Is being a Runge domain equivalent to being polynomically convex?**

Comment: Your definition of polynomially convex is not correct: the strict inequality sign must be replaced by $\leq$ and you should  require that $\hat K$ be compact but not that  $\hat K=K$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I agree with the strict equality sign, but what do you mean by your second comment? I took the definition straight from here http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Polynomial_convexity.

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote. The point is that neither you nor the linked article define what a polynomially convex **domain** is but only what a polynomially convex **compact set** is. For **polynomially convex  domains**  you should require that compact subsets $K\subset \Omega$ have compact polynomial hulls $\hat K$, but not that $K=\hat K$. By the way, with your  definition **no** nonempty domain in the universe is polynomially convex: I challenge you to find just one (even in $\mathbb C$) if you cling to your false definition !!

Comment: I agree with you, I am very new to this subject so sorry for coming of as arrogant.

Comment: No, no you are not arrogant at all . You have adopted the right  atitude: defend your position and if you see that something is indeed wrong, say so. By the way there are excellent books on the subject, written by real masters:  [Grauert-Fritzsche](https://books.google.fr/books/about/From_Holomorphic_Functions_to_Complex_Ma.html?id=jSeRz36zXIMC&hl=fr), L.Kaup-B.Kaup, Shabat . You would certainly profit from them.

Comment: More links: [L.Kaup-B.Kaup](https://books.google.fr/books?id=nDgBsOurnAIC&pg=PA326&lpg=PA326&dq=b.Kaup+l.kaup&source=bl&ots=7s-jaC2qn7&sig=oTuK9Vp5-rVqTXyMSI4V9jW_F2I&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=BMdfVYC-K-qv7AbCj4PwBg&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=b.Kaup%20l.kaup&f=false) , [Shabat](http://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/shabat-all.pdf)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, can you look at the comment below your answer? Why does the article claim that these two concepts are equivalent?
link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01420524.pdf in the first sentence he says "In [1] we gave an example of a domain in $\mathbb{C}^3$ which is analytically equivalent to
the polycyclinder in $\mathbb{C}^3$, but which is not a Runge domain." and links to ""An example concerning polynomial convexity".
I am still confused

Comment: Sorry, but  my contribution stops here: I don't wish to read that article.

Answer (score 3):

**The concepts are not equivalent:**

The open subset $\Omega=\mathbb C^2\setminus\{0\}\subset \mathbb C^2$ is Runge but not polynomially convex: indeed  for $K$ the unit sphere $||Z||=1$  centered at the origin  $\hat K$ is the non compact set $0\lt||Z||\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you =) Is it clear from the paper http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01420524.pdf that the bounded domain should also be polynomialy convex (and if not is there a way to prove it)?